Set expiry date in Permission Set Assignment using Flow
I am trying to update the expiry date of existing assigned permission sets using flow. However, it is not keeping the set date values after the assignment.
Approaches that didn't work:

Using the default queried collection of PSA and modifying it
Using a custom collection variable to store queried PSA
Using hard coded value for expiry date
Using formula to set expiry date value


Flow Debug Interview:


Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  Use [edit] and expose the Get Records and Loop elements.
